# remove a list of string from a column of list of strings

Tags: python

Its hard to describe the problem, but now I have a dataframe with a tokenized string, and I want to remove the most common words from it. So I got the list with the most common words and got the tail. But I don't know how to use this list to remove the words from the main column:

The column is like that:

> df['tokenized']
>
> ```
> {'dog', 'cat' , 'fish'}
>
> {'car', 'dog', 'water'}
>
> {'blue', 'red', 'green'}
> ```

Each row is a list of strings

if the list of words I want to remove is {'dog', 'cat'}

The desired output is:

> df['tokenized']
>
> {'fish'}
>
> {'car', 'water'}
>
> {'blue', 'red', 'green'}

Any help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
mcw = {'dog', 'cat'}
df['tokenized'] = df['tokenized'].apply(
    lambda lst: [word for word in lst if word not in mcw]
)
```

You should use a **set** for most common words, not a list (because it's much faster to check if an element belongs to a set).

Comment: df['tokenized'] return empty lists, so it doesn't work

Comment: it finally worked, but I forgot that I need the intersection not the difference, so it is much faster to treat it like an intersection

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
tokenized=[['dog', 'cat' , 'fish'], ['car', 'dog', 'water'], ['blue', 'red', 'green']]
most_common_words = ['cat','dog']
for l in tokenized:
    for w in most_common_words:
        try:
            l.remove(w)
        except ValueError: pass
print(tokenized)

# output:
# [['fish'], ['car', 'water'], ['blue', 'red', 'green']]
```

Comment: My problem is had a list of 80k values to remove so this code is worthless for me. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Please describe on the question what you want...

Comment: I could do this with this code  df['tokenized'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i != 'cats'] but if i put a list this code give me an error so I need to find a way to do something like that with a list

Comment: The time complexity of this algorithm is very high... I would not use it with a large dataset